# Display MKMapView grayscale

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

Is it possible to change MKMapView display to grayscale ?

Answer (score 8):

No, the MapKit API does not support any manipulation of the tiles. If you're interested in just a static grayscale map, you might be successful in taking a `MKMapSnapshot` and manipulate the image afterwards. This won't work for an interactive map, though.

You can also put a semi-transparent image view on top of the mapView. This won't allow you to completely decolorize the underlying mapView. However, you might achieve a similar effect. See the [Metropolis Compass app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metropolis-compass/id402848877?mt=8) for example.

Comment: Ortwin thanks for response. I tried it before which I put a semi-transparent image top of the mapview (actually thats what I needed). But this time my overlays goes to under the semi-transparent image view. I haven't solved this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could hit the map title API at google and recolor the titles and load them as a overlay. It would be a little hacky.

I knew some guys that did this in Flash. Google is ok with it with permission:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=cm0zMDkzOHZWMjJneEl2RVdkNFZRb0E6MA

Check out Cloudmade's alternative mapping toolkit : http://cloudmade.com/products/iphone-sdk

Edit:

You could maybe overload renderInContext and then repaint the screen somehow. It sounds a bit dangerous.

Comment: Hi Zac, Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm looking to recolor MKMapView to grayscale. Is it possible make it with overlay ?

Comment: Yep, I checked your comment. Then I asked a question to Mark Malone who is Integration Technologies Evangelist. He gave me an answer about it. It seems It's not possible to make it in MapKit.

Comment: Maybe I can try with CouldMake. It seems It's possible to make it with their styleEditor. Thanks by the way.